# Can I get a function for when I click the mouse a second time (not on the current window)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, buttonclick, pyautogui, pynput

first off I am new to programming and just learning the basics at the moment.
    I am creating a 'product picker' using python 3.7 (in pycharm) and want to mouse click on one of the product buttons then on my next mouse click paste/print/insert the product name into my invoicing system.

Currently my code works fine using the 'time' module to set a delay before it types allowing me to select where it is going to type it(line 49 of code).
  Here is my code:

I have already tried things like onMouseUp or onDoubleClick (i know these are not the correct code but you get the idea).

```
# import statements import modules
from tkinter import *  # tkinter helps create GUI's
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as keyboardController  # helps 
control keyboard functions
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Controller as mouseController  # helps 
control mouse functions
import time
import pyautogui


# since pynput.mouse and .keyboard have 'Controller' we have to rename them 
so 
both will work
keyboarad = keyboardController()
mouseclick = mouseController()

# defining some variables
root = Tk()
root.grid()
btn = {}
raw_col = 1


# product lists set into categories

product = [
            'product1',
            'product 2',
            'product 3',
            'product 4',
            'product 5'
]


def picker(product):

    time.sleep(3)
    keyboarad.type(product)
    time.sleep(.5)
    keyboarad.press(Key.tab)
    keyboarad.release(Key.tab)
    keyboarad.press(Key.tab)
    keyboarad.release(Key.tab)


# for each 'item in 'raw' list we want you to create a button
for item in product:

    btn[item] = Button(root, text=item, command=lambda x=item: picker(x), 
height=1, width=25)

    btn[item].grid(column=1, row=raw_col, pady=5, padx=5)
     raw_col += 1


mainloop()
```

what is actually happening at the moment is it waits 3 seconds then types
what i would like it to do is on next click types

Any help would be greatly appreciated, not just to get it working but help me learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `time.sleep(3)` suspends the mainloop for three seconds during which it is unresponsive. Try using `after()` instead as this will schedule an action for later but not suspend the mainloop.

**Update**
I thing I didn't quite understand what you were after. To print the previous choice at a click you'll have to save the state in some way. In my example I'm simply using a global variable:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
button_dict = {}

# product lists set into categories
product_list = ['product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3', 'product 4', 'product 5']

def paste_to_invoice(p):
    # Just to have a function as placeholder for invoicing system
    print('Previous choice was:', p)

last_pick = None    # Global variable to hold previous selection
def picker(product):
    global last_pick
    if last_pick != None:   # Is there a previous choice?
        paste_to_invoice(last_pick)     # Then print it
    last_pick = product     # Save this choice for next click

# for each 'item in 'raw' list we want you to create a button
for row, item in enumerate(product_list):
    b = Button(root, text=item, command=lambda x=item: picker(x))
    b.grid(column=1, row=row+1, pady=5, padx=5)
    button_dict[item] = b  # Save reference to button

mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for that I will update the code for that, but i would still like to get rid of it altogether in the end, by replacing it but something like onNextClick or something.

Comment: Updated my answer.